# Capistrano deployment is not happenning after Server IP Change

Tags: capistrano, puma, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

Problem: Recently We have changed IP address of the stage server. We are using Capistrano for deploying rails application. So after changing server IP address when we run a command: cap develop(branch name) deploy, it is not working. Please find below config files

deploy.rb

```
 # config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.10.0"

set :application, "app_name"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:repo.git"

set :branch, :develop

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/app_name'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/mongoid.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{ bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.3.1' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby
set :bundle_binstubs, nil

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false
set :puma_preload_app, false

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

config/deploy/develop.rb

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server "db.example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{db}
server '<new_ip>', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}

# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}



# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server "example.com",
#   user: "user_name",
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: "user_name", # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: "please use keys"
#   }
```

Not sure what we are missing, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error message do you get when the deploy fails?

Comment: I  am not getting any error but it is showing rvm version and ruby version like: (rvm 1.29.3 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]) ruby-2.3.1 after running command cap develop(branch name) deploy.After that nothing is happening.

Comment: Could you add the full output from running that command? It's difficult to figure out what's going wrong just from what is given.

Comment: run command with `--trace` flag, `cap develop(branch name) deploy --trace` and paste output into your question, please. It will help to understand your problem.